# Magento 2 : update existing where collection clause

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to update an existing collection where clause in _beforeLoad() function. The collection can be filtered on many attributes and I just want to replace the customer_id clause.
I was able to clear all where clauses by using the following code but I just want to clear the customer_id condition :

```
$this->clear()->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::WHERE);
```

Thanks !

Comment: Have you got solution of this?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can reset  at `_beforeLoad` method in your collection.

You may need to reset the `clause` at  *`renderFiltersBefore()`*  method.

```
protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
{  
    $this->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE);
}
```

As you want to remove one of field filter then have to work to at `_renderFilters`

```
 protected function _renderFilters()
 {
        if ($this->_isFiltersRendered) {
            return $this;
        }

        $this->_renderFiltersBefore();

        foreach ($this->_filters as $filter) {
        if($filter['field'] == 'customer_id'){
            continue;
        }   
            switch ($filter['type']) {
                case 'or':
                    $condition = $this->_conn->quoteInto($filter['field'] . '=?', $filter['value']);
                    $this->_select->orWhere($condition);
                    break;
                case 'string':
                    $this->_select->where($filter['value']);
                    break;
                case 'public':
                    $field = $this->_getMappedField($filter['field']);
                    $condition = $filter['value'];
                    $this->_select->where($this->_getConditionSql($field, $condition), null, Select::TYPE_CONDITION);
                    break;
                default:
                    $condition = $this->_conn->quoteInto($filter['field'] . '=?', $filter['value']);
                    $this->_select->where($condition);
            }
        }
        $this->_isFiltersRendered = true;
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my code $this->clear()->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::WHERE); is working great. The issue is this code reset all where conditions I only want to reset customer_id clause.

Comment: I tried using your _rendersFilters method but when I display the collection select I'm still get the customer_id condition : WHERE (`product_id` = '11') AND (`customer_id` = '71') because $this->_filters is empty when the function is called

Comment: I donot think it will create issue